# Regular Expression does not validate as I would want

Tags: c#, regex

I cannot validate user input so that only digits, apostrophes, letters A-Z, a-z and spaces are allowed when I add regular expression `[RegularExpression(@"[0-9][a-z'-]{3,20}")]` in this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace InspiringMagazines.Models
{
    public class Magazine
    {
        public int magazineID { get; set; }

        [MinLength(3),StringLength(20),Required(ErrorMessage = "The 
Magazine Name is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"[0-9][a-z'-]{3,20}")]
        public string magazineName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Price per issue")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [Range(5.00,20.00)]
        public double magazinePrice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

English letters A-Z, a-z, apostrophes, spaces, 3-20 letters inclusive and digits.

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot"?

Comment: "Can not add" is not a clear statement. Does it give a compile error? Does it compile but not behave as you'd want? What would you want to happen, and what is happening instead? Please **[edit]** the question and clarify as much as you can.

Comment: I edited it, is it better?

Comment: Still very unclear - why did you post the code above? does it work? what's not working about it? is the Regex you posted not what you want or is it just entirely not working? What have you tried?

Comment: The `{3,20}` works only for the `[a-z'-]` (which doesn't include uppercase letters or spaces!). The separate `[0-9]` means that the text should start with a single digit.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you splitted your classes, you need pattern:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z' ]{3,20}
```

Explanation:

`a-z` - all lowercase letters

`A-Z` - all uppercase letters

`0-9` - all digits

`'` - apostrophe or space

`{3,20}` - repeat at least 3 at most 20 times